# Allegro 5 from command-line OSX

Tags: c++, macos, allegro5

Though I am new to programming I can work with C++ and was trying to learn some basic Allegro 5 with some tutorials you can find on the Allegro Wiki. I'm using Mac OSX 10.7.5 from command-line (but I was thinking about trying Xcode maybe).
The error code I get when compiling [this tutorial project](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Basic_tutorial_on_loading_and_showing_images) (you can find the entire source code at the end of my post) with g++ (or with clang++) is:

```
$ g++ tutorial.cxx -lallegro -lallegro_main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_al_init_image_addon", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccdwG70k.o
"_al_show_native_message_box", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccdwG70k.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and, without using -lallegro and -lallegro_main,

```
$ g++ tutorial.cxxUndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_al_create_display", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_destroy_bitmap", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_destroy_display", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_draw_bitmap", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_flip_display", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_init_image_addon", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_install_system", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_load_bitmap", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_rest", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_al_show_native_message_box", referenced from:
  __al_mangled_main in ccWL3qZZ.o
"_main", referenced from:
  start in crt1.10.6.o
 (maybe you meant: __al_mangled_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I had no problem when compiling [this other tutorial](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial/Bitmaps).

Can you explain me what is the problem with the first program? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Here is the code of "tutorial.cxx", from the first link:

```
#include "allegro5/allegro.h"
#include "allegro5/allegro_image.h"
#include "allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP  *image   = NULL;

if(!al_init()) {
  al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to initialize allegro!", 
                             NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
  return 0;
}

if(!al_init_image_addon()) {
  al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to initialize al_init_image_addon!", 
                             NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
  return 0;
}

display = al_create_display(800,600);

if(!display) {
  al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to initialize display!", 
                             NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
  return 0;
}

image = al_load_bitmap("image.png");

if(!image) {
  al_show_native_message_box(display, "Error", "Error", "Failed to load image!", 
                             NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
  al_destroy_display(display);
  return 0;
}

al_draw_bitmap(image,200,200,0);

al_flip_display();
al_rest(2);

al_destroy_display(display);
al_destroy_bitmap(image);

return 0;
}
```

Many thanks,

George

Comment: What happens if you try `#include <allegro5/allegro.h>` (angle brackets instead of quotes)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion but actually I was experimenting with Allegro one year ago and now I'm working with other stuff.. :)